# Get first cell value of each row in table

Tags: jquery

Please help me to get first cell value of each row in table by click delete button, the below codes display cell values for all the cells. The table is generated by Ajax success function. So the table does not exist on page on-load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mytable td").click(function() {
     alert($(this).html());
     });
 });

</script>


 //html table , this is sample table , 

 <table border="1" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer Id</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td><button>Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td><button>Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0003</td>
    <td><button>Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you are looking for:

```js
$("#mytable td").click(function () {
  var selectValue = $(this).siblings("td").html();
  alert(selectValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer Id</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td><button>Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td><button>Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0003</td>
    <td><button>Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGYDq/)** demo of the code above.

Comment: @sam, just noticed in your profile you have no accepted answers. It's important for the people helping here that you click to accept answer. Then they get more score, and you also...

Comment: Sergio I'm really new here, very helpful, but "click to accept answer" ,how to do that?

Comment: @sam, on each answer you have a score number, voted by others, with "arrow" up and down ( in the left side). Just under it you have a symbol/check that you can click and it turns green. You can only accept one answer, the one you think is best and worked best for you. That person gets 15 points, you get 2 more. You can also vote up useful questions to give 10 points to that person/answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should get the first table cell of each row.

```
$('tr > td:first-child')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the first cell's text by clicking on a button in the same table row:

```
$(document).on("click", "table td button", function(){
    alert($(this).parents("tr").find("td:first").text());
});
```

Since it's using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) it works with AJAX generated tables as well.

jsFiddle DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fZ639/

Comment: @sam, you're welcome! don't forget to accept my solution! :) Let us know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

to get an array of all the values of the i'th column you can use

```
var i=0;
$('tr > td:nth-child(i)').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```